# Модификация метода

Tags: android, kotlin

Изначально у меня метод выглядит следующим образом:

```
override fun onListItemClick(itemIndex: Int, itemCode: String) {
    val data = adapter.getItem(itemIndex)
    if (data is TitleValueItem) {
        when (data.titleId) {
            R.string.v2_mobile_settings_language -> onLanguageClick()
        }
    }
}
```

теперь я его решил преобразовать таким образом:

```
override fun onListItemClick(itemIndex: Int, itemCode: String) {
    when(adapter.getItem(itemIndex) as? TitleValueItem? ?: return) {
        R.string.some -> onLanguageClick()
    }
}
```

И он мне ругается на строковый ресурс, что мол Int вместо TitleValueItem, не могу понять, что я забыл дописать то .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте следующим образом:

```
override fun onListItemClick(itemIndex: Int, itemCode: String) {
    when ((adapter.getItem(itemIndex) as? TitleValueItem)?.titleId ?: return) {
        R.string.v2_mobile_settings_language -> onLanguageClick()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Вот так попробуйте

```
override fun onListItemClick(itemIndex: Int, itemCode: String) {
    when((adapter.getItem(itemIndex) as? TitleValueItem? ?: return).titleId) {
        R.string.some -> onLanguageClick()
    }
}
```